# Is $\sin(kx) $ a complete system in $L^{2}(0,b)$ for every k in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: fourier-series, lp-spaces

Is the family $\{ \sin(kx ) \}$ a complete system in $L_{2}(0,1)$ for every $ k \in \mathbb{R}$, $k\geq1$ ? And less specifically, Is it a complete system in  $L_{2}(0,b)$  for every b$\in \mathbb{R}$ ?

I am trying to obtain a solution for a PDE using the Fourier method (Separation of Variables) but I need to obtain $b_{k}$ for :

> $ \sum b_{k} \sin(k\pi x)=f(x) $

And I am interested in using the formula:

> $b_k = \frac {\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \varphi_k (x) dx}{\int_{0}^{1} \varphi_{k} (x)^{2} dx }$

Comment: $L^2(0,1) : yes$------- $L^2 (a,b): no$.

Comment: Pedantic response: none of $\{\sin x\}$, $\{\sin 2x\}$, $\{\sin3x\}$, etc. are complete systems. (This is a response to how you put "for every $k$" outside of the set $\{\sin k x\}$. Also, do you mean $k\in\Bbb R$ or $k\in\Bbb Z$?) Nor is $\{\sin x,\sin 2x,\sin3x,\cdots\}$ a complete system, since $\cos$ cannot be written as an infinite sum of sines (because $\cos$ extends to a periodic even function but any sum of sines extends to a periodic odd function).

Comment: @whacka My notes say it is a complete system in $L^2(0,\pi)$ for $k \geq 1 $ . What I want to know is if it is a complete system in $L^2(0,1)$. I am particularly interested in what I remark, $\{sink\pi x \}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$.